# Is items threshold (5000) effected by "Item Version History" feature?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have huge list with more than 3000 items, I need to activate "Item Version History" feature on this list, Is this will effect the items threshold (5000)on the views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, version history is not related to List View Threshold. An item is still considered a single item even if it has many versions.

Comment: thank you, but the every version will save as an item within the same database table, and I don't know it the version column is indexed or not, and as you now the 5000 Threshold is an SQL issue. anyway, can you provide me with any reference about this.

Comment: I don't have any reference but it is quite easy to test. Create a simple console app, add 1000 with each item having 10 versions. Then see if queries are throttled.

Comment: I'll test and inform soon

Comment: @jobin, did you get a chance to test this?

Comment: unfortunately no, I'm preparing SP machine for that, because when I asked the question I was using SharePoint online. thank you for interesting